# Error when trying to start ubuntu software center

Tags: apt, software-center, google-chrome

Hello my problem is i tried to install Google chrome from this site https://www.google.com/intl/en/chrome/browser/?&brand=CHMA&utm_campaign=en&utm_source=en-ha-na-us-bk&utm_medium=ha when i did i downloaded what i think it the wrong file and now I don't know what do to do get my software center working when ever I try to start it it doesn't work it just closes I've tired some commands such as

```
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

but that didn't work i then tried

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

and it also did nothing for those to thing i got this error message

```
E: The package google-chrome-stable:i386 needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.
```

If someone could help that would be nice I really don't know what to do I a newbie :c

Answer (score 0):

This Will **NOT** Help You Fix Your Software Center Problem, But It **WILL** Get Google Chrome Installed.

Download the .deb Google Chrome File. 32 bit or 64 bit (Depending On Your Operating System Version). To Find What Version You Have Search For "Details" In The Dash. You should see something that says "OS Type". It will tell you 32 bit or 64 bit. Download the according file. Install GDebi Package Manager Using This Command: `sudo apt-get install gdebi` . Navigate To Your Downloaded .deb file in your downloads. Right Click On It And Select Open With Gdebi Package Installer. In Gdebi Click Install Package. Once It Finishes, Search For Google Chrome In The Dash. It Should Be There.
Hope This Helps!

Answer (score 0):

Probably, You have installed Ubuntu 13.04 Raring Ringtail, Google Chrome can't be installed in Ubuntu 13.04 Raring Ringtail (fresh install) for now because of a missing dependency: libudev0. Until Google fixes this, here's how to install the missing dependency so you can use Google Chrome (any version) in Ubuntu Raring.

first you want to install libudev0 from here:

[libudev0 for 32bit](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/udev/175-0ubuntu19/+build/4325790/+files/libudev0_175-0ubuntu19_i386.deb)

[libudev0 for 64bit](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/udev/175-0ubuntu19/+build/4325788/+files/libudev0_175-0ubuntu19_amd64.deb)

After you have Installed libudev0 Package to Ubuntu 3.04 Raring Ringtail, Now you can install Google Chrome